# Disable file picker and file explorer in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

We want to have a machine showing a web page in Kiosk mode. We are using the `-kiosk` flag when launching the browser. However, we would want to prevent any user from reading the file system. In this case, preventing Chrome from opening the File Explorer when a user clicks in an input field with `type=file`. Is it possible to disable this API?